# Varios iconos en map leaflet VueJs

Tags: vue.js, leaflet

Tengo un map el leaflet que carga los puntos dinamicamente desde una api de esta forma:

```
<l-marker
    v-for="punto in puntos.data"
    :key="punto.name"
    :lat-lng="punto.position"
    ref="btnRef"
    >
  <l-icon
      :icon-url="marcador_var"
 />
<l-marker/>
```

Quisiera que cada punto tuviese un icon diferente en función al nombre, pero no he logrado pasar el parametro variable al momento que estoy cargando la colección, itero la data que me llega de esta forma:

```
data.forEach((element) => {
        let coordenadaArray = element.UbigacionGPS.replace(/"/g, "")
          .replace(/[[\]]/g, "")
          .split(",");
        var dato = {
          name: element.Codigo,
          position: coordenadaArray,
        };

        this.puntos.data.push(dato);
        this.marcador_var = marcador  
        
        this.polyline.latlngs.push(coordenadaArray);
      });
```

Intente pasar a traves de:

```
this.marcador_var = marcador
```

pero no funciona, toma para todos el primero que haya pasado, alguna forma de poder hacer variables estos marcadores?